# Store subquery with WITH for re-use in IN statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to store a list of values from a subquery to reuse across my query in IN statements:

```
WITH ListOfIds AS (SELECT Id FROM Users)
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Foo WHERE Foo.UserId IN ListOfIds)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bar WHERE Bar.UserId IN ListOfIds)
```

It is not valid. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
WITH ListOfIds AS (SELECT Id FROM Users)
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Foo 
WHERE Foo.UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM ListOfIds)
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Bar 
WHERE Bar.UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM ListOfIds)
```

It is a bit pointless though.

And probably `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. I don't see a point to skip counts.

---

You should stay with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Foo 
WHERE Foo.UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM Users)
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Bar 
WHERE Bar.UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM Users)
```

I guess that query optimizer is smart enough to get list of `Id` once.

Comment: I just wonder if there any reason to actually use this syntax instead of a straight-forward `UNION`.

Comment: @PM77-1 There is non, query optimizer is smart enough or not to calculate `SELECT Id FROM Users` once.

Comment: query optmizer is smart enough to not recalculate this list of ids?

Comment: @WalterMacambira Probably, check execution plan.

Comment: Unless the actual query for `ListOfIds` is a huge multi-join.  Then it will be more readable with `WITH`.